# Llamar dos métodos diferentes (JavaScript y C#) a un mismo boton

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Tengo esta problemática, quiero llamar dos métodos, uno es JavaScript (`sendMail();`) y el otro es C# (`Button2_Click`), en un solo botón:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server"  Height="36px" class="btn btn-warning " OnClick="Button2_Click" OnClientClick="sendMail(); return false"  Text="Aprobar" Width="129px" />
```

Necesito que las dos funciones se ejecuten al mismo tiempo.

Comment: Al mismo tiempo no creo que se puedan ejecutar, primero se ejecuta el javascript y luego el codebehind, y quita el return false del OnClientClick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolví de otra forma, llame el método de JavaScript al código  C#:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ eliminar();ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"Button2", "sendMail();", true); }
```

Comment: Puedes aceptar tu propia pregunta :) Para +info: [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

La forma en que muestras tu código es correcto, excepto por el `return false` que tienes en el evento `OnClientClick`. Si al ejecutar el evento obtienes un resultado falso, ya no se ejecuta el evento `OnClick`. Lo ideal será que en la función regreses un `false` o un `true`, dependiendo del resultado para que tu botón quede de la siguiente forma:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server"  Height="36px" class="btn btn-warning " OnClick="Button2_Click" OnClientClick="sendMail();"  Text="Aprobar" Width="129px" />
```